# redirecting after downloading PDF in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

i'm currently working on a project where I want to have a button that after clicked, it will generate a PDF and then reload the page. currently there are two return statements but how can i combine them into one to achieve my goal?

this is my code:

```
return redirect()->action('DashboardController@index');
return $pdf->download($getDetail->ID.'_Letter.pdf');
```

please help

Comment: There's no simple way to redirect them, have you tried starting the pdf download and then calling the redirect. When you call return all the code afterwards is not executed

Comment: do you mean $pdf->download(...)->redirect()->action('...') ?
i did and it gave me this error:
Method Illuminate\Http\Response::redirect does not exist.

Comment: I meant `$pdf->download($getDetail->ID.'_Letter.pdf'); return redirect()->action('DashboardController@index');`

Comment: it doesn't download, because according to barryvdh the download is a response.

Answer (score 0):

Just use this:

```
Response::download('file_to_download', 'end_user_filename', ['location' => '/path_to_url']);
```

Comment: hey, i tried out your code but I got the following error
"Object of class Barryvdh\DomPDF\PDF could not be converted to string"
i was using this to generate the pdf

Answer (score 0):

Make a URL in Your route like

```
Route::get('download-file', 'XXXXController@XXXXMethode')->name('XXXX');
```

for action  and write this code in controller method this

```
public function XXXXMethode()
{
    $file_path = public_path('path/XXXX.filetype');

    return response()->download($file_path);
}
```

You call this url directly from your page where you want to redirect